# selected feature from DataFrame has a different length when passing to sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

When I use:

`df_train[df_train.columns.drop('Survived')]`

it return me a 891*17 dataframe.
But when I want to extract the labels with `df_train['Survived']`, the length changes to 892.

How can this happen? All columns have the same length in the dataframe.
When I try to convert my dataframe into a dict with `dict(df_train)` it also shows me, that all columns have 891 values but 'Survived' has 982.

I stumbled across this when receiving the error

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [891, 892]
```

when trying to call this function:

```
cv_results = model_selection.cross_validate(alg, df_train[df_train.columns.drop('Survived')], df_train['Survived'], cv=cv_split)
```

[image]
[image]

Edit:

I run multiple MLA in a loop like this: (just before this code bit the lengths were equal)

```
MLA_predict = df_train['Survived']

cv_split = model_selection.ShuffleSplit(n_splits = 10, test_size = .3, train_size = .6, random_state = 0 ) 
row_index = 0
for alg in MLA:

    #set name and parameters
    MLA_name = alg.__class__.__name__
    MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Name'] = MLA_name
    MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Parameters'] = str(alg.get_params())

    #score model with cross validation: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_validate(alg, df_train[df_train.columns.drop('Survived')], df_train['Survived'], cv=cv_split)

    MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Time'] = cv_results['fit_time'].mean()
    MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Train Accuracy Mean'] = cv_results['train_score'].mean()
    MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Test Accuracy Mean'] = cv_results['test_score'].mean()   
    #if this is a non-bias random sample, then +/-3 standard deviations (std) from the mean, should statistically capture 99.7% of the subsets
    MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Test Accuracy 3*STD'] = cv_results['test_score'].std()*3   #let's know the worst that can happen!


    #save MLA predictions - see section 6 for usage
    alg.fit(df_train[df_train.columns.drop('Survived')], df_train['Survived'])
    MLA_predict[MLA_name] = alg.predict(df_train[df_train.columns.drop('Survived')])

    row_index+=1
```

Comment: What is the value of `cv_split`?
Also, just FYI, it's simpler to write `train_df.drop('Survived', axis=1)` if you want to drop a single column (give a list for multiple columns)

Comment: @Zionsof Thanks. I edited my post to include the part with the function call and the split. But I am not sure what you mean by value.

Answer (score 0):

The MLA_predict needs to be a different object!

`MLA_predict = df_train['Survived'].copy()`